# Why list_a = list_a.append(1) will produce a NoneType instead of through an Error?

Tags: python

If this would pop out an error, as a python newbee, I wouldn't need to find out my mistake for a whole hour!

So I'd like to ask What's the consideration and benefit of this mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[append()](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is a method on a list which just adds an item to the end of a list and returns nothing. In other words, it modifies a list "in place":

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> type(l)
<type 'list'>
>>> l = l.append(4)
>>> print l
None
>>> type(l)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

And, since `NoneType` is actually [a valid and perfectly normal variable type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.NoneType), `l` becomes `None` without any errors - just think about it as `l = None`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: And also for addition, in Python, methods that modify an object, return None by convention.

Similarly, `l.sort()` returns None while it sorts `l` and if you want to return the sorted one, you can use `sorted(l)`

Comment: That explains why `list_a` doesn't have a meaningful value (something about which the OP did not seem to be confused). It does not explain why it's not an error.

Comment: @sepp2k fair point, thanks. Hope the explanation explains it enough for the OP.

Comment: I got it, if I say list_a = list_a.append(1), I'm expecting list_a will equal anything return by append function. As append function  always returns a value None. So that list_a became None. Is it?